# What is the typical best practice methodology around transferring money between two distinct systems?

Tags: multithreading, transaction, locks

I got this question on an interview the other day and was clueless to what the best practices are for solving it.  It's the issue where you have to transfer money between two systems and want to avoid double counting.  The systems are not located in the same hosting environment and each is web accessible through a gateway.  How are situations like this typically handled?  I know you need to establish a lock in both systems before you can proceed transferring money from one account and putting it in another.  But what if you establish locks in both systems, then request to debit money from one system and don't get a response?

Curious about best practices here.

Comment: You already alluded to the solution in the tags you've placed on your question:  **use a transaction.**  Using a transaction guarantees an "all or nothing" result.  If it's between two different systems, sometimes it's called a *distributed transaction.*

Comment: As to locks and multithreading, I'm not sure what you think they have to do with these sort of transactions.  Relational databases (and other data stores with certain consistency guarantees) have their own means of resolving concurrency problems.

Comment: Generally, they're handled using some 40 year old fixed width file format that makes you question human civilization...

Comment: @RobertHarvey, I think if I would have responded, "Use a transaction" in my answer I would have been asked to elaborate.  Given you are dealing wiht two distinct systems, what is the general protocol for establishing a lock around both?   Are there any other precautions needed around things like timeouts?

Comment: Read here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_transaction

Comment: `Given you are dealing with two distinct systems, what is the general protocol for establishing a lock around both?` Buy something in Amazon, wait for a day or two, then check your bank account. You will see that Amazon asked your bank for "locking" an amount equals to the product price. The bank will lock the amount and schedule the transfer for its later execution. Transfers are 2 atomic operations on both sides (subtract, add). **If any operation fails, it's performed a compensative operation (refund)**. See compensative operations as a sort of rollback, which can also fail :-).

Comment: In the end, the most important is "traceability" and "tracking". In distributed computing, these both features are a MUST HAVE. Because things happen and not everything can be handled and repaired automatically. In these cases, we need (badly) a way to figure out what went wrong and how to proceed to restore (manually) the consistency of the data.

Answer (score 5):

So the first thing that you have to understand is that real world systems that accounts do not have a single total that is added-to and subtracted from.  Instead what they have is a set of transaction records that represent inflows and outflows from an account.  Determining the balance of the account is (to oversimplify) reading through all the financial transactions and adding them up (including the negative numbers).

When money is moved from one system to another, it's more-or-less complete when you have a record in each system's account.  The source account having a negative amount and the target having a positive amount.

Based on my experience as bank customer, the way the problem you are asking about is managed is roughly that the transactions are created and marked as being in some sort of in-process/incomplete state until both have received confirmation that the other system has received it.  There are likely also confirmations of receipt of confirmation.

DB Transactions or [distributed transactions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_transaction) like [two-phase commit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-phase_commit_protocol) are useful for this kind of thing but are not strictly required.  You might find reading more about them to be illuminating as this kind of problem is fundamental to networked systems and these protocols implement the kinds of approaches required to make this reliable.

Comment: Quick follow up to "accounts do not have a single total that is added-to and subtracted from."  Does that mean every time a customer views their balance, there is a real time calculation of all the transactions?  That seems extremely I/O intensive and inefficient especially for customers with many transactions.

Comment: @Dave: It depends on the system.  Some banking systems "close out periods," so the calculation wouldn't have to be made from the beginning of time. It would be easy enough to cache such a value, if you were careful.

Comment: Hi @Robert, I can ask this as a separate question if it would be easier, but if institutions calculate the total based on a cached value plus all the transactions from a given period of time until today, why not skip the last part and just have a cached value for everything?  I'm not understanding the advantage of only adding some transactions in order to obtain a total.

Comment: @Dave: Revising a figure in a closed-out period can be very difficult.

Comment: @dave - Computers are _really_ good at adding up numbers. Doing that for a few thousand transactions is trivial. And given the risk involved in getting those calculations wrong, spending a few dozen milliseconds is way better than trying to keep caches synced.

Comment: @Telastyn to add, a big part of it being done that way is being able to verify that the number is correct.  Some systems may keep track of the 'current' balance but that would always be in addition to the list of transactions.  Consider if you looked at your bank account and you thought the total was wrong.  If the bank couldn't show you how they came up with that number, that would be a big problem.